# Running Python codes with cuda support in Google Colab

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, pytorch-geometric

I don't have GPU support in my Macbook pro. I uploaded a directory of codes in Google colab to make use of the Cuda support. However, I see the code is unable to access other files in folders in the current directory. Please advise.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eANO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyBKi.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-upload your files or reconnect to Google Drive again after changing the runtime to GPU.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to mount your drive by using the following script.

> from google.colab import drive

> drive.mount('address of your directory')

Comment: Thanks. I know that works except is it safe to give Google Colab full access to your drive even for the time you are running your codes

Comment: If you want to use google colab, you have to accept it. In my experience, I never had any safety-related problems but this is worth mentioning.